# Temporarily switch off bindings in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

The title of the question is bad, feel free to update it.

I have an observablecollection that generates a user control whenever it an item has been added to it. 
However there are times where I just want to add to the collection and not have it create a usercontrol. Is there a way around this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a collection view around the observable collection and bind the UI to that. The collection view will have a filter so that only items you want in the UI are filtered in

Comment: Hey @pickles When I get into work tomorrow I will try your suggestion, and an upvote if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Lol I couldn't wait to check it out. Brilliant! Thanks :)